# How would I go about integrating this problem?

Tags: integration

$$ \int_0^3 (x^2-3x).sin(\frac {n\pi x}3) $$

To my understanding I should use integration by parts but I am confused by the limits as they would be used twice in int by parts.

This is what I have done so far:

$$ u = x^2-3x $$

$$ \frac {du}{dx} = 2x -3 $$

$$ v = \frac {3}{n \pi}.cos( \frac {n \pi x}{3}) $$

$$ \frac {dv}{dx} = sin( \frac {n \pi x}{3}) $$

Then put this into the integration by parts equation $ \int uv - \int v.\frac {du}{dx} dx $:

(Skipping to $ \int v.\frac {du}{dx} dx $)

$$ \frac {3}{n \pi}.cos( \frac {n \pi x}{3}).(2x-3) $$

$$ [ \frac {6x-3}{n\pi}.cos(\frac{n\pi x}{3})]_0^3 $$

Substituting $ x $ with $ 0 $ gives $ 0 $.

Sub $ x $ for $ 3 $.

$$ \frac {15}{n \pi}. \frac {3}{n \pi}.cos(n \pi) $$

$$ \frac {45}{n^2 \pi^2} . cos(n \pi) $$

Overall:

$$ [\frac{3x^2-9x}{n \pi}.cos(n \pi) - \frac {45}{n^2 \pi^2}.cos(n \pi)]_0^3 $$

Is this correct so far? When I go ahead and put in the limits I get the following which doesn't seem to match Wolfram Alpha:

$$ - \frac{27}{n^2 \pi^2}.cos(n \pi) + \frac {45}{n^2 \pi^2}.cos(n \pi) $$

Answer (score 0):

*I was just about to post this on your previous question before it was deleted*

---

I think you are heading in the right general direction. This is how you could go about the question:
$$ \int_0^3 \left(x^2-3 x\right) \sin{\left( \frac{ x n \pi }{3}\right)} \, dx $$
You can use the integration by parts formula:
$$ \int u' v=uv -\int u v' $$
which in this case $u'=\sin{(x n \pi/3)}$ and $v=x^2-3x$. So we need to integrate $u'$ to find $u$ and differentiate $v$ to get $v'$:
$$ u=-\frac{3\cos{\left( \frac{\pi n x}{3} \right)}}{\pi n} \;\; \text{and} \;\; v'=2x-3 $$
Thus you can put these into the integration by parts equation to give:
$$\int \left(x^2-3 x\right) \sin{\left( \frac{ x n \pi }{3}\right)} \, dx=
-\frac{3 \left(x^2-3 x\right) \cos{  (\frac{\pi  n x}{3})}}{\pi  n}-\left(-\int\frac{3 (2 x-3) \cos  (\frac{\pi  n x}{3})}{\pi  n} \;\text{d}x\right)
   $$
Which looks a little messy but you can see that the only integral we now need to evaluate is: 
$$ \frac{3}{n \pi}\int (2x-3)\cos\left(\frac{n x \pi}{3}\right)\;\text{d} x $$
which can again be done by parts to hopefully give the correct answer.

---

**Continuation:**

We can evaluate the integral above by parts again (you can expand it, though it makes the algebra worse):
$$  \frac{3}{n \pi}\int (2x-3)\cos\left(\frac{n x \pi}{3}\right)\;\text{d} x $$
You can do this with $v=(2x-3)$ and $u'=\cos\left(\frac{n x \pi}{3}\right)$. Which I'm sure you can fill in the in-between steeps there, just follow what I did above. Then once you've evaluated the relatively simple integral of $\cos\left(\frac{n x \pi}{3}\right)$ you can put it all together to get:
$$ \frac{9 (\pi  n (2 x-3)  \sin({\frac{n \pi x}{3}}) +6 \cos({\frac{n \pi x}{3}}) )}{\pi ^3 n^3} $$

Which if you plug into all the things above (eventually) gives:
$$ \frac{\cos ({\frac{n \pi x}{3}}) \left(54-3 \pi ^2 n^2 (x-3) x\right)+9 \pi  n (2 x-3) \sin{(\frac{n \pi x}{3})}}{\pi ^3 n^3} $$
which after plugging the limits of the integral in give:
$$ \frac{27 (\pi  n \sin{(\pi  n) } +2\cos{ (\pi  n)} -2)}{\pi ^3 n^3} $$

---

*What is this from? it seems like a rather complicated integral (unless I'm missing something).*

Comment: Is it essential to take out $ \frac {3}{n \pi} $?

Comment: No you can leave them in if you want, it just makes it a little neater.

Comment: Well I left it in on mine and I get the same answer as you, could you possibly move on to the next part? I'm trying to work out where I have gone wrong. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Yeah I'll add a little more to help clarify what you could do next.

Comment: Actually i noticed I didn't switch the cos to sin, however I think I have made one more mistake. Thank you so much for the help.